# Objective C - when to use NSNumber vs a Primitive

Tags: ios, objective-c

if you know that a certain Integer will need to be used as an object in at least one point in its life cycle, should it be declared and used as `NSNumber` from the beginning?

I know that calculations should be done using primitive data types and so you say `[NSNumber numberWithInteger: myInt]`. But if 90% of time you only need a basic data type, does the other 10% justify creating an `NSNumber` and constantly using `[NSNumber intValue]` to retrieve your primitive? Are there noticeable performance advantages to sticking with a primitive as long as possible or do the OO advantages of `NSNumber` outweigh those?

As a newcomer to Objective C, I'm also curious what the best practice is -- coming from languages like Ruby and PHP where this doesn't occur.

Comment: Hm I'm actually asking about the primitive Int type, not NSInteger

Comment: @ChrisLoonam ah I now see the answer a couple below the accepted one which has info on my question. Thanks!

Comment: Generally use `NSInteger` (which is typedef for either `long` or `int`), unless you explicitly need an object for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSNumber` is somewhat rare in Objective-C. Certainly not unheard of, but somewhat rare. If you're in doubt, you want to use `NSInteger`. I've written whole, large programs without a single `NSNumber` in them.

The most common use for `NSNumber` is when you want to put it into an `NSArray`, `NSDictionary` or serialize it (for example into `NSUserDefaults`). Most of the time, numbers are just a property of some other object, as an `NSInteger`.

Comment: I see. I suppose I'm not asking so much about NSNumber specifically. I'm asking about using a primitive  (int) vs an object-version (NSNumber, NSInteger, etc)

Comment: NSInteger is not an object. It's just an alias for int or long, depending on your platform. NSInteger is usually what you want in Cocoa because it matches what the frameworks expect. NSNumber, on the other hand, is an object. It is only used when you really need an object for this number.

Comment: Ah I see. So per my question, if i know that a number will eventually need to be in an NSArray at some point in its life cycle, does it make sense to declare it an NSNumber from the beginning? Or create an NSInteger and only create an NSNumber for when I need to add said integer to an array?

Comment: Most of the time, NSInteger is still the right tool, until you really need NSNumber. Most of the time it comes down to whatever is easiest for the code, but I have rarely needed NSNumber in a property.

Answer (score 3):

My advice is to use primitive types unless the values will spend a great deal of time in collections (NSArray, NSDictionary, etc.).  The `@(myInt)` syntax is fairly clean, for those times you need an NSNumber.

The one exception I'd keep in mind is when you need to know if the value was ever initialized.  In this scenario, unless you have a clear "uninitialized" value (such as zero, NSNotFound, -1, etc.), using NSNumber set to nil makes an easy and deterministic way to tell what you have.

Comment: Thanks for the info, and good call on the short syntax `@(myInt)`!

Answer (score 2):

Basically, don't use `NSNumber` unless you actually, currently need to.

If some API you are using expects `NSNumber`s, then generate those `NSNumber` instances on-demand. Basically, use primitives for computations, for storing information, and even in your APIs (e.g. public class properties) as long as it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, you can do most part of C, so of course, if you needn't to do something about object, you can always use primitive types until you get desired result. Then if you want to insert it in a NSArray or show in UILabel or something, transfer it to NSNumber.

NSInteger is a combination of int/long due to different of 32bit/64bit, other primitive type like float has no problem about this, so only a special OC edition primitive type NSInteger.

NSNumber and primitive type are like Integer vs int in Java I think. You need primitive type to do arithmetic, and NSNumber to do operation about it's object situation and memory space. They can not do the work of the other side.